# How to assign a value to a fixed array of pointers to structs

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create an array of structs with a dynamic size and try to assign values to each of those structs.  I know that I could use vector to easily solve this, but I'm doing this as an exercise to learn the underpinnings of C++ and how it really works at its core.

The struct in this case is

```
struct car
{
        std::string make;
        int year;
};
```

Then within the main() function, I have:

```
car* cars[catSize];
for (int i = 0; i < catSize; ++i)
{
     cars[i] = new car
     cout << "Enter the make for car " << i << ": ";
     char ch;
     string tempMake = "";
     cin.get(ch);
     while(ch != '\n')
     {
           tempMake += ch;
           cin.get(ch);
     }

     cars[i]->make = tempMake;
     cout << "Enter the year of car # " << i << ": ";
     cin >> cars[i]->year;
}
```

Running the above gives me a segmentation fault immediately after entering a make and pressing enter.  Can someone help explain what is going on?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using objects and not `new`?

Comment: catSize is a user-inputted integer - so in this case, I put in a value of 3.

Comment: Time to compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g`) and to **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: As stated above, I know I can use std::vector.  I'm trying to avoid that for the purposes of this exercise so I can understand how the native types work.

Comment: Why don't you `car *cars = new car[catSize];`?

Comment: `std::vector` is as native to C++ as `int`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I fundamentally disagree with your premise.  I'm already adept in Javascript, Python, Java, and many other languages.  I used C++ in college but not much since. In fact, I think it is a great failing of the software industry today that more people *don't* understand what is going on behind the scenes.  Knowledge of how computers and software actually work can help contribute to solving problems in the future.  Take JavaScript - it's easy to learn, but when you know how it actually *works* you have much more power in coming up with solutions to problems.

Comment: @SteveJessop , indeed ;-)

Comment: @mjsalinger. I think Steve's tongue is firmly in his cheek. The default SO kneejerk reaction is 'use `std::vector`' . It shouldn't be ;-)

Comment: @n.m. I agree it's frequently the right answer, but as shown here, it can also be an unhelpful kneejerk reaction.   *"just mention that in the question"* : The OP did exactly that.

Comment: Um, I have completely missed that. I'm bad and I feel bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that after you input the array size, the `'\n'` stays stays in the input buffer and interferes with further input.

Moreover, you should have `catSize` as constant since `VLAs` are not supported with all compilers.

If you still want to use VLA, then you should add `cin.ignore();` after reading the array size.

Also, you should note that at present it is not a **dynamic array of structs** as stated in your question, but a **fixed array of pointers to structs**.

Comment: This ultimately worked.  Adding a cin.ignore() fixed the problem.  It is worth noting that I ran into the same issue after the first time through the for loop, as the \n from entering the year was still left in the buffer, so it assumed that as input for the next input of make.